# aws-sdk v3 javascript, condition expression wont work for put command

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries

I want to create putItem function, where it prevents overwriting previous item if 'userId' already existed. Upon searching, I figured that one can use condition expression in the params object before passing to putcommand from aws-sdk. But the problem is, it still update the item, even though the userId has existed. Need your help if anyone can review my code and tell me where I did wrong. Thank you.

```
import { PutCommand } from "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb";
import { ddbDocClient } from "./ddbDocClient.js";

const putItem = async (newItemObject) => {
    //check for userId
    const userId = {newItemObject};
    if(userId){
        console.log({userId});
        // Set the parameters.
        const params = {
        TableName: "portal-users",
        Item: newItemObject,
        ConditionExpression: "userId = :userIdVal",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":userIdVal" : userId,
        }
        };
        try {
            const data = await ddbDocClient.send(new PutCommand(params));
            console.log("Success - item added or updated", data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error", err.stack);
        }
    } else {
        console.log('user id is undefined, please provide for new user id');
    }
};

const newUser = [
    {
        userId: 'user01',
        nameFirst: 'alison',
        nameLast: 'swift'
    }
]

newUser.map(x => putItem(x));
```

Comment: a little addition, I also tried ConditionExpression: "userId <> :userIdVal", but also it wont work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `userId` will always equal `:userIdVal`, as thats the key you are using.

What you need to use is [`attribute_not_exists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.PreventingOverwrites)

```
const params = {
    TableName: "portal-users",
    Item: newItemObject,
    ConditionExpression: "attribute_not_exists(userId)"
};
```